# c# Xamarin Change CutterBehavior of UIKit.UIPrintInteractionController.ChooseCutterBehavior

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, printing, xamarin.ios

I have a probably simple question for every pro coder:
I would like to write an iOS app with xamarin in C# that prints html to a  receipt printer. For that I would like to adapt the default Cutterbeavior of the receipt printer.

i have this Code which works perfect for me:

```
var printer = UIPrintInteractionController.SharedPrintController;
            printer.ShowsPageRange = true;
            printer.ShowsNumberOfCopies = true;
            printer.ShowsPaperSelectionForLoadedPapers = true;
            var page = @"<!DOCTYPE html><style></style><html><head><meta charset='UTF-8'><title>Title</title></head><body>Text to print</body></html>";
            var textFormatter = new UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter(page);
            printer.PrintFormatter = textFormatter;
            printer.Present(true, (handler, completed, err) =>
                {
                    if (!completed && err != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("error");
                    }
                });
```

and now i would like to customize this property:
`printer.ChooseCutterBehavior`

Unfortunately, the documenation does not help me any further:
https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/UIKit.UIPrintInteractionController.ChooseCutterBehavior/

How can I set the property ChooseCutterBehavior? Unfortunately, I can not continue at this point and I am grateful for any hint!

Thanks!

Comment: check out the Apple docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiprintinteractioncontrollerdelegate/1618178-printinteractioncontroller

Comment: Hi Jason, thank you. But i struggle with the correct syntax in C#. Can you give me an example?

Comment: No idea.  Iv'e never used this API, and even Apple's sample code doesn't use it.  You might try asking on the Apple dev forums, but the answer they might give you will be in Swift or Obj-C

Comment: Maybe I'm on the wrong way? `printer.ChoosePaper` could also be an option. but also here I have no idea how to set the property

Comment: have you read the Apple docs on printing in iOS?

Answer (score 0):

In your `IUIPrintInteractionControllerDelegate` implementation, add the optional `printInteractionController:chooseCutterBehavior:` method.

This method **may be** called by the printer driver and will give the available (`UIPrinterCutterBehavior`) behaviors that this printer supports. You return one of the supported behaviors based upon your requirements.

```
public class MyPrintInteractionControllerDelegate : NSObject, IUIPrintInteractionControllerDelegate
{
    [Export("printInteractionController:chooseCutterBehavior:")]
    public UIPrinterCutterBehavior ChooseCutterBehavior(UIPrintInteractionController printInteractionController, NSNumber[] availableBehaviors)
    {
        // What does this printer support?
        foreach (var whatsAvailable in availableBehaviors)
        {
            var nameofEnum = Enum.GetName(typeof(UIPrinterCutterBehavior), whatsAvailable.Int16Value);
            Console.WriteLine($"AvailableBehavior : {nameofEnum}");
        }

        // If the printer supports CutAfterEachJob, use it, otherwise use the whatever the printer default is.
        if (availableBehaviors.Contains((int)UIPrinterCutterBehavior.CutAfterEachJob))
            return UIPrinterCutterBehavior.CutAfterEachJob;
        else
            return UIPrinterCutterBehavior.PrinterDefault;
    }

    //~~~ other delegate methods ~~~
}
```

Now assign the delegate (`IUIPrintInteractionControllerDelegate`) to your `UIPrintInteractionController.SharedPrintController` instance:

```
var printer = UIPrintInteractionController.SharedPrintController;
printer.Delegate  = new MyPrintInteractionControllerDelegate();
```

Comment: That does not work for me. my `ChooseCutterBehavior` Method is never called. May be it is the wrong return type? i think it is supposed to be `UIPrintInteractionCutterBehavior` not `UIPrinterCutterBehavior` . Do you have any idea how to return a `UIPrintInteractionCutterBehavior` value?  Thanks!!

Comment: @FSP You might want to read the Apple docs on how this works: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiprintinteractioncontrollerdelegate/1618178-printinteractioncontroller

Comment: sorry, i am very new to c# and xamarin. I have seen the Apple docs but unfortunately that does not help me. Can you give me an example?
This line 
`if (availableBehaviors.Contains((int)UIPrinterCutterBehavior.CutAfterEachJob))`
from your code does not work for me because NsNumber[] does not have definition for "contains".
Also, the ChooseCutterBehavor function in your example is never called and I can not figure out why. Thanks!

Comment: @FSP `.Contains` comes from `System.Linq`, i.e. `using System.Linq;` Assuming the delegate (`IUIPrintInteractionControllerDelegate`) is assigned to the printer controller, it is up to the printer driver to call those methods, if the printer does not have paper cutter (or did not implement it in their driver), the `_:cutLengthFor:` delegate method and those the length of the paper (in points) is never asked for. Same for the `UIPrinterCutterBehavior`, if the printer does does not have that feature or did not implement it on iOS, the behavior is not asked for. What printer are you using?

Comment: Thanks for your `using System.Linq` hint. now "contains" works but is still never called. 

My Printer is a "Star TSP654II" with AirPrint, Ethernet, WLAN and Cutter. Obviously my Printer does not call the method (via airprint) But the cutter is working. When I print a html output, it does not matter how long the text is. currently it cuts every page. But I do not want to cut until the end of the job. That's why i want to set `UIPrinterCutterBehavior.CutAfterEachJob`. do you think this is the wrong way?

Comment: @FSP Try implmenting some of the other delegate methods (i.e. ChoosePaper,  ChoosePaper, WillStartJob). They will be called a various times during the presentation of the printer controller, etc... ChooseCutterBehavior will be called during the run of actual print job if the printer provides the option to AirPrint (in your case). Use the "Simulated Label Printer" (via the `Printer Simulator.app` in the `Additional_Tools_for_Xcode` download) and choose either the 2" or 4" roll paper for it to test your code as that printer with a continuous paper roll calls for the cutter behavior.

Comment: @FSP Then try your Star printer again to see if the call is made. Personally I've use a lot of the Star printer line but avoid AirPrint, too slow and not enough control over the output, i.e. there are receipts produced when we partial cut vs full cut after each copy vs. each job. Items like this are not available via AirPrint....

Comment: For me airprint seemed to be the most obvious way. Maybe it's the wrong way. How do you handle the printers? Do you have a link or an example? Thank you for all the tips and your patience!

Comment: @FSP AirPrint is "good" at what it does... (with the Star line, I use their StarPRNT / PassPRN APIs, but they are not for the faint of heart ;-) Since you already have the HTML output done for AirPrint, use the "Printer Simulator.app" as I suggested above to test your code as that simulated printer does use the cutter behavior when a continuous paper roll is used.

Comment: Now I have tested with the "simulated label printer" and role paper. (i did't now it. This is really cool for testing!) Again, a long html text is displayed on several pages in the output.pdf and the ChoosCutterBehavior method is still not called. I can not figure out why

Comment: @FSP Gotta love simulated printers, saved at least a tree or two in all the iOS testing I've done  :-)  That printer's `ChooseCutterBehavior` should be called with the available behaviors of NoCut, PrinterDefault, & CutAfterEachPage and that will happen right before the `WillStartJob` delegate protocol/method is called. Are you assigning the controller's delegate? Are other delegate methods triggering? Are you using the delegate that Xam will create if you assign an a `Func` against one of the exposed delegate methods on the `UIPrintInteractionController` itself?

Comment: @FSP  Do not mix the two, you can not have multiple delegates, last one assigned wins. (Poor design choice by Xamarin to add this C# normalization without a guard on the `.Delegate` property, has burned many of my clients....)

Comment: i started over with a new project and now my delegate method is called. Sorry, I do not know what it was..
as you say simulator respons is "NoCut, PrinterDefault, & CutAfterEachPage". But my Star Printer still does not call my ChooseCutterBehavior. 
it seems like this is not implemented in the driver via Airprint.
Therefore, I suspect that I have to solve my problem via a customized PageSize? For this I have created the "ChoosePaper" delegate method, which is (now) also called. I can see which paper is available.
But I can not figure out how to set a Height (that fits my Output).

Comment: Glad you got it working at least.... There is a `CutLengthForPaper` protocol: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiprintinteractioncontrollerdelegate/1618179-printinteractioncontroller

Comment: This sounds very good. But with the apple doc i can't get it working. it is not calling my "cutLengthForPaper" Method. May be the naming or the type of my Method is wrong? i have this `[Export("printInteractionController:cutLengthForPaper:")]
        public nfloat CutLengthForPaper(UIPrintInteractionController printInteractionController, UIPrintPaper paper) {nfloat cutLength = 1000; return cutLength;}`

Comment: Ok, i got it. cutLengthForPaper is now called and is working. `[Export("printInteractionController:cutLengthForPaper:")] public nfloat CutLengthForPaper(UIPrintInteractionController printInteractionController, UIPrintPaper paper)
        {            var CutLength = new nfloat(1000.0);
            return CutLength;
        }`

Comment: but I'm desperate with my Star Printer. CutLengthForPaper is also only called with the Printer Simulator. When I use the Star TSP Printer, he does not use this method. Do you have any idea how I can do that?

Comment: same problem here. Using that same printer the cut delegate is not called. The other delegates are called but the cutLengthFor and the chooseCutterBehavior. I cannot connect to printer simulator so I don't have a way o test that, but the printer does not call those delegate methods.